# How to execute vimdiff command from inside a java program

Tags: java, vim, vimdiff

I have a list of files for which I have to run the vimdiff command and save the output as a html file.I am doing this with Java. Below is the command I am trying to execute

```
String cmd = "vimdiff -c 'set foldlevel=9999' src/test/resources/testdata/output/html_output_before_changes/file1.html src/test/resources/testdata/output/html_output_after_changes/file2.html -c TOhtml -c 'w! different.html' -c 'qa!'"
```

When I run the below code, the code is getting executed. But I am not able to see the file getting generated.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = rt.exec(cmd);
```

The command is running fine when executed from a terminal. But its not working when executed inside a java program. Can someone help me with this issue? I did a lot of search but not able to proceed with this.

Comment: In which directory is the java process running?

Comment: The java program is running within the following directory src/test/java/com/company/content/ft/tests/CompareBeforeAfterHTMLFiles.java

Comment: No, It isn't. What is the full path?

Comment: /Users/username/Documents/gitrepo/reponame/src/test/java/com/company/content/ft/tests/CompareBeforeAfterHTMLFiles.java. This is the full path of the java file. I am executing the java code from this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After Two days I found the below Solution:**

I added the vimdiff command to a shell script and executed it using the following method and it worked like a gem.

**Java method**

```
try {
            File[] uiDiffDir = getFiles();

            for (File file : uiDiffDir) {

                String[] cmd = {"sh", shellScriptPath, file1, file2,
                        outputfile};
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                p.waitFor();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        p.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**shell.sh**

```
vimdiff -c 'set foldlevel=9999' $1 $2 -c TOhtml -c 'w! '"$3"'' -c 'qa!'
```

**Note:**

- file1 will be passed as a argument in the place of $1
- file2 will be passed as a argument in the place of $2
- outputfile will be passed as a argument in the place of $3

Answer (score 1):

You're using `:TOhtml` and write the result as `different.html`. If you're not sure where to locate the file, check the current working directory of the Java process, do a file search of your hard disk, or specify an absolute path in the Vim command to be sure.

You won't see anything from Vim's operation itself. Using `process.`[`getInputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()), you *could* obtain what Vim wrote to the terminal during its operation, but that would just amount to a garble of characters, as Vim is using special ANSI escape sequences to control the terminal, position the cursor, etc.

To use Vim non-interactively, it is recommended to pass the following options:

```
-T dumb           Avoids errors in case the terminal detection goes wrong.
-n                No swapfile.
-i NONE           Ignore the |viminfo| file (to avoid disturbing the
                  user's settings).
-c 'set nomore'   Suppress the more-prompt when the screen is filled
                  with messages or output to avoid blocking.
```

Without a possibility to interact with Vim (from inside your Java program), a troubleshooting tip is enabling verbose logging: You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `-V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for errors.

Comment: I tried providing the path for the output html also.  vimdiff -c 'set foldlevel=9999' /Users/kmohanavelu/Documents/contentserv/contentservFunctionalTests/src/test/resources/testdata/output/html_output_before_changes/PPC000331_GB_en_GB_31bdc2f5cd58ef2b.html /Users/kmohanavelu/Documents/contentserv/contentservFunctionalTests/src/test/resources/testdata/output/html_output_after_changes/PPC000331_GB_en_GB_31bdc2f5cd58ef2b.html -c TOhtml -c 'w! /Users/username/Documents/gitrepo/reponame/src/test/resources/testdata/output/html_code_comparison/different.html' -c 'qa!'

Comment: This command is working from terminal but not from the java program. That's the issue I am facing

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear from your question. I've added some more recommendations and troubleshooting tips; that's all I can do. If you suspect problems with the missing terminal, you could try starting `gvim` instead, or wrap the Vim invocation in a terminal emulator (e.g. `xterm`). Starting Vim non-interactively from Java is not a good solution IMHO.

Comment: The suggestions did not work out. I tried all the options but did not work. But after so much search I found a solution. Updated the solution in my question. Please see above. But thanks for reaching out a helping hand. I am much grateful :)

Comment: Glad you've figured it out; making it more modular with a wrapper script is a good idea (though I still don't see the root cause of the problem). Don't forget to consider the Vim options I've mentioned, too!

Comment: Yup I won't forget it!! Thanks